# example of usage for wordnik

Tags: iphone, wordnik

Does anyone have an example in Objective C that uses the wordnik apis?
The repo on Git hub offers a set of classes with pretty much no explanation of how to put together the pieces (rather than what libs you need to make it compile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to get data from the API pretty easily:

1. Include the ASI & JSON code in your project
2. Ensure you have Foundation.framework, CoreServices.framework, libz.1.2.3.dylib, SystemConfiguration.framework
3. In your code initializer, import ApplicationConstants.h and set your API key:

```
    Import "ApplicationConstants.h"

    ...
    API_KEY = @"{YOUR_API_KEY}";
```

5. make some calls:

```
    WordService *ws;

    ws = [[WordService alloc] init];
    NSArray* definitions = [ws fetchDefinitions:@"dog"];    
    Word *w = [ws fetchRandomWord:TRUE];
```

There will be a proper sdk in objective-c and other languages for the purposes of aggregating some of the basic Wordnik API calls.

Tony

Answer (score 0):

The code on GitHub is a basic starting point for a Wordnik library and forms pretty decent example and probably better than anything anyone can come up with here on the spot.

The classes form the starting point of a Wordnik API library, giving you a base service, and a few subclasses implementing more specific parts of the API, for example definitions. There are a few model classes modeling wordlists, definitions and parts of speech etc.

To use them, you'd include the source in your app, and then create an instance of one of the services, eg, the `WordService` and invoke the `fetchDefinitions:` method, passing the word you want to define as a parameter.

This will result in an array of `Definition` objects being returned, which you can use in your app.

The idea is that the core logic of making requests, downloading data, parsing the response and handling errors are abstracted away from you within the service classes.